# Contact form in php not sending in certain circumstances

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, contact-form

Having a problem with the php scrip used to send a form on my website. It works in on situation but not in a second situation.

**Situation where it's working:**

html form is located in the root directory of mydomaine.com

sendmessage.php is located in the same root directory

the forms calls a javascript file located in mydomaine.com/js/

within that javascript I have the code below, notice the    "../sendmessage.php"

```
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '../sendmessage.php',
                data: $("#contact").serialize(),
                success: function(data) {
                    if(data == "true") {
                        $("#contact").fadeOut("fast", function(){
                            $(this).before("<p><strong>Success! Your message has been sent, thank you.</strong></p>");
                            setTimeout("$.fancybox.close()", 1000);
                        });
                    }
```

**Situation not working:**

html form is located in mydomaine.com/test/en/

sendmessage.php is located in mydomaine.com/test/

the forms calls a javascript file located in mydomaine.com/test/js/

within that javascript I have the code below, notice the    "../sendmessage.php"

To me it looks OK since the js file needs to load sendmessage.php one level down (mydomaine.com/test/) (I also tried to remome the "../" but still not working)

```
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '../sendmessage.php',
                data: $("#contact").serialize(),
                success: function(data) {
                    if(data == "true") {
                        $("#contact").fadeOut("fast", function(){
                            $(this).before("<p><strong>Success! Your message has been sent, thank you.</strong></p>");
                            setTimeout("$.fancybox.close()", 1000);
                        });
                    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks, actually found out the issue, I uploaded the updated javascript file in the wrong directory!

Answer (score 0):

Need more details on what is not working and the code for js/html and php. Looks simple enough and should work but there maybe other references to path in your old directory structure that may not be updated for the new directory structure.

Also turn PHP errors on as well as look for apache logs.

Comment: Thanks, actually found out the issue, I uploaded the updated javascript file in the wrong directory!